# Build or Buy Bluetooth 4.0 BLE Tag

Tags: iphone, nfc, bluetooth-low-energy, tag

I am planning to create a mobile application that scans a NFC tag and performs an action based on the unique scan (tap). Because Apple iPhone do not support NFC I am forced to look for an alternate option i.e BLE 4.0 (at least works for iPhone and android)

***MY NEEDS***

1. I just need to trigger the action when the user is very close (like a Tap). Not looking for a geo-fencing or location-sensing use case.
2. Had iPhone supported NFC, I would not have needed BLE Tag. A cheap NFC tag would have solved my need.
3. Pairing is absolutely not possible for my app. User case just does not fit. User should be able to tap any Tag without pairing

***BUILD OR BUY***

1. The are plenty for BLE Tag providers in market (BlueCats, Estimote, Sonic notify etc), but they are turning out to be a bit expensive for me (all in the range of $15-20 in bulk). If I have to install 50 beacons per location and may be 1000s of locations, that's a big cost.
2. There are few chip makes like TI and Nordicsemi. Would it be cheaper to get it manufactured with help of an OEM manufacturer?
3. Any tips/best practices if I decided to Build instead of Buy?
4. Should I even think of Building one?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: Thanks Leon. Understood. I am a first time user and do no understand electronics. Can you please also tell me what would have been the right place ?

Comment: How is a cost benefit analysis of BUILDING VS BUYING NOT ABOUT ELECTRONIC DESIGN?